# kubectl rollout status for ALL deployments in a namespace

Tags: kubernetes, rollout

I have a number of deployment objects in my namespace. I'd like to run `kubectl rollout status` for all of them at the same time. So, I'd like the command to exit, only when all rollouts are complete, or an error has occurred. How can I achieve that?

The only thing I got with so far is:

```
kubectl get deploy -o name | xargs -n1 -t kubectl rollout status
```

But I hope there's something smarter.

Comment: I don't think you can do that.

Comment: Are the deployments related? If so, defining a helm chart might make sense

Comment: The deployments are in a helm chart, but I am not using `--wait` on the helm chart as it has a bug -> https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/3173

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I guess what I came up is the best there is.

```
kubectl get deploy --output name | \
  timeout -t 300 \
    xargs -n1 -t \
      kubectl rollout status
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use this simple check:

```
#!/bin/bash
deploy=$(kubectl get deploy -o name)
for i in $deploy; do kubectl rollout status $i -w --timeout=30s; done
```

You can also build more advanced script using clues in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37448357/ensure-kubernetes-deployment-has-completed-and-all-pods-are-updated-and-availabl/37472801#37472801).